# How to get name of document.onkeydown function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, dom, dom-events

`document.onkeydown.toString()` returns `onkeydown` function but I only want to get this function's name.

Is it possible?

```
var exHandler;
function getCurrentHandler(){
   currentHandler = document.onkeydownhandler.toString() - i want to get name of this to call setPreviousHandler with exHandler

document.onkeydown = newFunction;

setPreviousHandler(exHandler);
}

function setPreviousHandler(targetHandler){
   document.onkeydown = targetHandler;
}
```

Comment: document.onkeydown = current function (i dont know the name)
document.onkeydown = my function

I want to set document.onkeydown to the current function which i changed before.

Comment: Can you please write that down in pseudocode?

Comment: So you don't need name - you can get reference to handler with `var currentHandler = document.onkeydown;` change handler to other: `document.onkeydown = newFunction;` and later use stored handler, e.g. `setPreviousHandler(currentHandler);`

Comment: @MateuszW yes, i did as you said, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the way the function was assigned.
Take look at this:

```
function test() { alert('test'); }
window.onkeydown = test;
window.onkeydown.toString();
```

output is `function test() { alert('test'); }` and you can parse this string to get its name as string:

```
var fnsting = window.onkeydown.toString(); 
// use regexp to extract name
var name = fnsting.match( /function\s*(.*?)\s*\(/ )[1]; // name is 'test'
```

(it will allways returns name from function definition (when you assing this function to other variable `.toString()` always returns the same string)

but following example:

```
window.onkeydown = function () { alert('test'); };
window.onkeydown.toString();
```

will print `function () { alert('test'); }` because this function is anonymous, so you can't get its name.

Moreover when you create function like this:

```
var test = function () { alert('test'); };
window.onkeydown = test;
window.onkeydown.toString();
```

and output will be `function () { alert('test'); }` because on creation function did not have name (it was function expression assigned to variable) so you also can not extract it's name.

But you can make simple comparision:

```
function foo() { alert('foo'); }
var bar = function () { alert('bar'); };

window.onkeydown = foo;

// try to find function
if (window.onkeydown === foo) {
    alert('this is foo');
} else if (window.onkeydown === bar) {
    alert('this is bar');
}

// or like this:
var handler = window.onkeydown;
if (handler === foo) {
    alert('this is foo');
} else if (handler === bar) {
    alert('this is bar');
}
```

But there is also issue with this, because when you assign anonymous function like this:

```
window.onkeydown = function () { alert('test'); };
```

You don't have any other reference to this function (it is not assigned to other variable) so you can't compare it with other function (comparision always returns false).

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. Function names are not distinct in javascript. Example:

```
function john() {
    // ... do something ...
}

var jim = john;
```

What would you now consider the name of that function? "john" or "jim"? - they both point to the exact same thing and are not different in anything. Another example may clarify that:

```
var john = function() { /* ... */ };
var jim = john;
```